# Filters on clustered Marker [HERE maps JS API]

Tags: here-api

I created a map with many Clustered markers with `getClusterPresentation` and `getNoisePresentation`.

my data is set like that :

```
{
 address: "Store 1 address",
 brands:["BRAND1", "BRAND4"],
 lat: "40.82346",
 lng: "5.2345",
 name: "Store 1 Name"
}, 
{
 address: "Store 2 address",
 brands:["BRAND2", "BRAND4"],
 lat: "40.82346",
 lng: "5.2345",
 name: "Store 2 Name"
},
```

I need to create a filter by brands to show / hide my markers. I don't know how to do it. How can I access a specific clustered marker with a specific brand (ex : 'BRAND2') and control his visibility.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create new `H.clustering.DataPoint`, you can specify optional parameter **opt_data** which will be associated with the given DataPoint. For more information about DataPoint see: [DataPoint class apireference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics_api/h-clustering-datapoint.html#h-clustering-datapoint__class-description).
Then your noisePoint in `getNoisePresentation` callback will contain this data and you can access it by calling `getData()` method.

```
// assume data is stored in "data" array, create new DataPoints array:
data.forEach(function(obj) {
  points.push(new H.clustering.DataPoint(obj.lat, obj.lng, undefined, obj));
})
.
.
.
// now we can work with this data in getNoisePresentation callback:
getNoisePresentation: function(noisePoint) {
  let data = noisePoint.getData(),
      visibility = data['brands'].includes('BRAND2');
  return new H.map.Marker(noisePoint.getPosition(), {
    min: noisePoint.getMinZoom(),
    visibility  
  });
}
```

Here you can find full working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvojka/jtvpreqn/) which hides one noise point (Store 1) if map is zoomed in.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try it as soon as I can.